# C# address Button using a string

Tags: c#, string, button, object-address

I have a Problem with addressing a button. I have many buttons in my program and I have a function which is used by every button.
I'm getting the name of the last clicked button with this:

```
foreach (Control t in this.Controls)
{
    if (t.Focused)
    {
        ClickedButton = t.Name;
    }

}
```

Then I want to change the Text of the button:

```
ClickedButton.Text = "Whatever";
```

But I can't use ClickedButton as the name of the button.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this in an event? Post the surrounding code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is an event, you can just do something like this

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
btn.Text = "Whatever";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having the clicked button call into the Click event, you should have sender as an argument, which you can cast to a Button and get the name of the control.

Since you have the button reference, you could then also set the control's text.

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    if ((b != null) && (b.Name == "btnTest"))
    {
         b.Text = "yay";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing this in your `button_click` event,

You can Get the button like this :

```
Button BTN = sender as Button;
BTN.Text = "This Button Has Been Clicked!";
```